# Customize datatable data Loading when there are many records

Tags: jquery, datatable

When there are many records in database, dataTable takes too long time to load. So i need to know is there any way to load database records as 10 by 10 or something like that.

Comment: Do you consider paging support on the back end?

Comment: yes. i consider. i'm developing vue+laravel application

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootgrid http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/examples where you can show data based on limit.

Comment: dataTable is used in my system. my project is under developing, so i can't change dataTable option.

Comment: There is server side datatables you can go for that https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side